# how to count number of firms in one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have big data(db) and in one column (NAME) I have the name of firms, according to it I want to calculate the number of firms in this column in panda. I used this code:

```
`db.groupby(['NAME'])['NAME'].count()`
```

and below the result I find this :

```
` Name: NAME, Length: 1889, dtype: int64`
```

I found the length is 1889, is it the number I want or not? how can I write it? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily  use :

```
len(df['name'].unique())
```

it will give how many unique value is in the name column.

Comment: thanks, this codes result the number of each firm separately for example firmA 17, firmB 20 frimC 13, but I want to find for example there are 3 firms A,B and C not the number of each firm